# Split string into string list containing strings no greater than n chars

Tags: f#

I have a long string that I need to convert to a string list where each string in the list is <= 50 chars.

In addition, I don't want words to be split - if the 50th char is a letter in a word, then I want the split to occur at the preceding space.

Therefore, the following string:

**What river rises in the Black Forest, flows through the Iron Gate, and empties into the Black Sea?**

Should become a string list containing the following strings:

```
What river rises in the Black Forest, flows 
through the Iron Gate, and empties into the Black 
Sea?
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you show your attempts to solve this problem?

Comment: Coming from a C# background, my attempts have been all over the place and very non-functional. That's why I didn't post code as that would only pollute the question. I started by doing a very manual step-by-step approach of split the strings into words (effectively strtok) and then iterating over each string in the list, adding each substring to the temp string until it reaches 50 chars in length, and then adding that temp string to my return string. Anyway, it's all very ugly; hence my hopes that someone would educate me on the correct way to do this.

Comment: I believe there is no single 'correct' way. In this case I would modify the question to describe what kind of solution you want: shortest, quickest etc.

Comment: well that is a **well know** problem ;) .... fire up you favorite search engine and look for "word wrap kata" - you will find plenty of solutions in ever language you want ;) (for examle [this](https://github.com/LeedsCodeDojo/WordWrap/blob/master/Grant_Fsharp/WordWrap/wrapper.fs))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of the [example](https://github.com/LeedsCodeDojo/WordWrap/blob/master/Grant_Fsharp/WordWrap/wrapper.fs) @Carsten linked to, here's a version to generate a list of strings instead of concatenating them all together as that linked example does:

```
let until index (text:string) =
    text.[0..index-1]

let from index (text:string) =
    text.[index..]

let wrap fullText lineLength =
    let untilLineLength = until lineLength
    let rec wrapRecursive (text:string) existingLines =
        if text.Length <= lineLength then
            (List.rev ((text.Trim())::existingLines)) //|> String.concat "\n"
        else
            let wrapIndex,nextLineIndex =
                match (text |> untilLineLength).LastIndexOf(" ") with
                | -1 -> lineLength, lineLength
                | spaceIndex -> spaceIndex, spaceIndex + 1
            ((text |> until wrapIndex).Trim())::existingLines |> wrapRecursive (text |> from nextLineIndex) 

    wrapRecursive fullText List.empty
```

I commented out the `String.concat` in the recursive base case to show how to easily convert this to outputting the concatenated string instead. My example also should be tail-recursive, unlike the linked example by introducing an accumulator list to the recursive function.

Testing it:

```
let fullText = "What river rises in the Black Forest, flows through the Iron Gate, and empties into the Black Sea?"

let lineLength = 50

let res = lineLength |> wrap fullText

printfn "%A" res
```

Output of:

> ["What river rises in the Black Forest, flows";  "through the Iron
>   Gate, and empties into the Black"; "Sea?"]